# Programming NASM, a startup guide?

Tags: linux, unix, assembly, x86, nasm

I am interested in programming assembler for Intel x86 architecture and on Linux. After some initial research this lead me to believe out of FASM, NASM and MASM I wanted NASM.

From this point on, how easy is it to write a NASM assembler "text file" on Linux and execute it? Is it relatively simple? What packages (gcc etc) do I need to ensure are installed? Does anyone know any walkthrough guides? I havent been able to find anything yet. Does it matter which linux distro?

Comment: [Google?](http://www.google.com/search?q=linux+assembly+tutorial) I note that one of the first few links points to a question here on SO with some useful information.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what flavor of Linux. On Ubuntu, install is as simple as `sudo apt-get install nasm`. After that, you might start at the NASM Project's [links page](http://www.nasm.us/links.php), which will lead you to approximately a zillion tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

The best one that I have found on the web, is [John Carter's PC Assembly](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/). It aim NASM, it's comprehensive, yet conscious and also it aims at Linux and Nasm.
All you need to know to start, can be found in first few chapters. Also it's been published under GPL licence .